# Error in output.println() on Processing

Tags: file, compiler-errors, serial-port, processing

I'm trying to read some data from Processing and write it to a file. The data is correct, since I can plot it without problem. However, when I attempt to write it to a file it throws me the following error:

```
Error, disabling serialEvent() for /dev/ttyACM0
null
```

Specifically, I've found out where the problem is. It's in this function:

```java
void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
  int inByte = myPort.read();
  if (inByte >= 0 && inByte <= 255)
    {
    // This is what makes the problem arise
    output.println("test: "  + inByte);

    // ...
    }
  }
```

I've even changed the line output.println(); with this and then the same function works, printing it to the correct file (but it's obviously not what I want):

```java
// This does work
point(mouseX, mouseY);
output.println(mouseX);
```

Any idea where the problem might be? I'm using arduino and it passes values from 0 to 255 from serial. The values seem correct, since I can plot them without problem. I've also tried changing `println()` for `print()` with no luck.

EDIT. After some testing, I find this really odd. This works:

```java
point(mouseX, mouseY);
output.println(inByte);
```

While, without the point(), it doesn't work (same error). As a temporary solution, I can put the output.println at the end of the function, but this is obviously not a long-term solution.

Comment: its just a wild guess but maybe its a timing issue, all the point function does is slow down your code. could you add something like a sleep or pause? also you could try to place a "flush" after the "println"

Comment: I was thinking about the same actually, but for the solution I'm going to try something else instead. Because the serial data is constantly being received, I'm going to have a check to attempt to write it only if the file is already opened (if Processing allows that check). Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing a simple check in my code:

```
if (output != null) {
  output.println(t + " " + inByte);
  }
```

It just works. However, I think that [polymorphism would be even better here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc). Having an object that absorbs the text if the output is not initialized, and that prints it to the file if it is.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but here is my solution and it works perfectly.

- at the beginning of the code write sth like this:

  `boolean outputInitialized = false;`
- after `output = createWriter(filename.txt);` put following:

  `outputInitialized = true;`
- the `output.print` function has to be included in an if-function:

  `if (outputInitialized) {
   output.println(filename);
  }`

Comment: I completely forgot to answer my own question. I used a really similar method, but with a small change that accounts for even less code and makes it more simple. I post it as an answer in case you're interested. However, I account that [polymorphism would probably be better here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc).